# Sort multidimensional array based on 2nd element of the subarray

Tags: python, arrays, list, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have an array like this:

```
[['G', 10], ['A', 22], ['S', 1], ['P', 14], ['V', 13], ['T', 7], ['C', 0], ['I', 219]]
```

I'd like to sort it based on the 2nd element in descending order.
An ideal output would be:

```
[['I', 219], ['A', 22], ['P', 14], ... ]
```

Answer (score 98, accepted):

`list.sort`, [`sorted`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) accept optional `key` parameter. `key` function is used to  generate comparison key.

```
>>> sorted(lst, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
[['I', 219], ['A', 22], ['P', 14], ['V', 13], ['G', 10], ...]

>>> sorted(lst, key=lambda x: -x[1])
[['I', 219], ['A', 22], ['P', 14], ['V', 13], ['G', 10], ...]

>>> import operator
>>> sorted(lst, key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
[['I', 219], ['A', 22], ['P', 14], ['V', 13], ['G', 10], ...]
```

Comment: Too late but Can you explain to me what the **lambda** function does?

Comment: The return value of the lambda will be used as sort key. About `lambda` itself, please read the python documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html?highlight=lambda#lambda-expressions

Comment: is operator.itemgetter(1) faster than lambda?

Answer (score 12):

Use `itemgetter`

```
from operator import itemgetter
a = [[1, 3, 5], [2, 511, 7], [17, 233, 1]]
a = sorted(a, key=itemgetter(1))
```

Output : [[1, 3, 5], [17, 233, 1], [2, 511, 7]]

`itemgetter` can also be used to sort by multiple subarrays.

Answer (score 7):

Do this:

Sort the multi-dimensional array in descending order on the basis of 2nd column:

```
list_name.sort(key=lambda x:x[1],reverse=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
x= [[8, 9, 7],
    [1, 2, 3],
    [5, 4, 3],
    [4, 5, 6]]
x.sort(cmp=lambda x,y: cmp(x[0],y[0]))
print x
```