# How to sort alphanumeric list in python

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a list as

```
a = [["1", "ok", "na"], ["15", "asd", "asdasd"], ["100", "uhu", "plo"], ["10", "iju", "tlo"], ["ISC_1", "des", "det"], ["12", "asd", "assrg"], ["ARF", "asd", "rf"]]
```

I want this list to be sorted as below:

```
[['1', 'ok', 'na'], ['10', 'iju', 'tlo'], ['12', 'asd', 'assrg'], ['15', 'asd', 'asdasd'], ['100', 'uhu', 'plo'], ['ARF', 'asd', 'rf'], ['ISC_1', 'des', 'det']]
```

I have used a.sort()

It is resulting as below:

```
[['1', 'ok', 'na'], ['10', 'iju', 'tlo'], ['100', 'uhu', 'plo'], ['12', 'asd', 'assrg'], ['15', 'asd', 'asdasd'], ['ARF', 'asd', 'rf'], ['ISC_1', 'des', 'det']]
```

Please help me how to sort in this case.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20099669/python-sort-multidimensional-array-based-on-2nd-element-of-subarray possibly answer your question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Sort Multidimensional Array Based on 2nd Element of Subarray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20099669/python-sort-multidimensional-array-based-on-2nd-element-of-subarray)

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `key` named argument.
It accepts a function that returns the value the sorting function should compare items by.

```
sorted(a, key = lambda l: int(l[0]))
```

Comment: Will it work in python2.7 ?  getting below error `>>> sort(a, key = lambda l: int(l[0]))

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#43>", line 1, in <module>
    sort(a, key = lambda l: int(l[0]))
NameError: name 'sort' is not defined`

Comment: with ´a.sort(key = lambda l: int(l[0]))´ or
´b=sorted(a,key = lambda l: int(l[0]))´

Comment: what if the case my list is
a = [["1", "ok", "na"], ["15", "asd", "asdasd"], ["100", "uhu", "plo"], ["10", "iju", "tlo"], ["ISC_1", "des", "det"]]

Comment: It is throwing invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'ISC_1'

Comment: what do you want do happen with ISC? should it come last or first? if it should come last: a.sort(key = lambda l: int(l[0]) if l[0].isnumeric() else 99999)

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response Leonhard Triendl
Yes ISC_1 should come last.
Here another question is if list has oe more alphanumeric as "AFC_1" then it should be "AFC_1" and then "ISC_1" as follows  "[['1', 'ok', 'na'], ['10', 'iju', 'tlo'], ['15', 'asd', 'asdasd'], ['100', 'uhu', 'plo'], , ['ARF', 'asd', 'rf'], ['ISC_1', 'des', 'det']]"

Comment: I will Update my question

Comment: @Shanky I have provided an alternative which may cover more bases for you

Answer (score 3):

To be ready for non numeric values you can use

```
a.sort(key = lambda l: int(l[0]) if l[0].isnumeric() else 99999)
# or
b=sorted(a,key = lambda l: int(l[0]) if l[0].isnumeric() else 99999)
```

to see non-numeric last or

```
a.sort(key = lambda l: int(l[0]) if l[0].isnumeric() else 0)
# or
b=sorted(a,key = lambda l: int(l[0]) if l[0].isnumeric() else 0)
```

to see them first

Comment: Thanks for the response.
I want the result as [['1', 'ok', 'na'], ['10', 'iju', 'tlo'], ['12', 'asd', 'assrg'], ['15', 'asd', 'asdasd'], ['100', 'uhu', 'plo'], ['ARF', 'asd', 'rf'], ['ISC_1', 'des', 'det']] With ARF first and ISC_1 last

Answer (score 3):

You can use a natural sorting key, very easy to setup with the regular expression `re.split()`

```
import re
try:
    # fast string checking and conversion
    from fastnumbers import *
except:
    pass

def natural_sort_key_for_list_of_lists(sublist):
    return [int(element) if element.isdigit() else element
            for element in re.split("([0-9]+)",sublist[0])]
    # put whichever index of the sublist you want here ^

a = [["1", "ok", "na"],
     ["15", "asd", "asdasd"],
     ["100", "uhu", "plo"],
     ["10", "iju", "tlo"],
     ["ISC_1", "des", "det"],
     ["12", "asd", "assrg"],
     ["ARF", "asd", "rf"]]

a.sort(key=natural_sort_key_for_list_of_lists)

for l in a:
    print (l)
```

result:

```
['1', 'ok', 'na']
['10', 'iju', 'tlo']
['12', 'asd', 'assrg']
['15', 'asd', 'asdasd']
['100', 'uhu', 'plo']
['ARF', 'asd', 'rf']
['ISC_1', 'des', 'det']
```