# Python Sort Multidimensional Array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, sorting

I need to sort an array of arrays by a specific element

This is an array:

```
arr= 
[0, [71, 554, 258, 793]]
[1, [61, 415, 148, 593]]
[2, [91, 145, 658, 893]]
```

I need to be able to sort it by `arr[0][0]` as well as by any element from the internal array like `arr[0][1]` or `arr[0][2]`

currently, I'm able to sort it by using `key=itemgetter(1)`
where: `itemgetter(1)` - is second element of array `[0, [71, 554, 258, 793]]`
in this cese = 71

```
from operator import itemgetter
array = sorted(array, key=itemgetter(1))
print(*array[:], sep="\n")
```

how to sort this array by any element from the internal array `[71, 554, 258, 793]`?

so if I'm sorting by the second element from internal array output should be like this: (column 145,  415,  554)

```
arr= 
[2, [91, 145, 658, 893]]
[1, [61, 415, 148, 593]]
[0, [71, 554, 258, 793]]
```

if I'm sorting by the third element from internal array output should be like this: (column 148,  258,  658)

```
arr= 
[1, [61, 415, 148, 593]]
[0, [71, 554, 258, 793]]
[2, [91, 145, 658, 893]]
```

this is kinda similar to this question: [Python Sort Multidimensional Array Based on 2nd Element of Subarray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20099669/python-sort-multidimensional-array-based-on-2nd-element-of-subarray)

Comment: sorted(arr, key=lambda x: x[1][1])

Comment: How are you stuck with this?  You simply replace that `1` constant with a variable that contains the column number.

Comment: @Prune  I wish it would be so straight forward but it's not, u see that index 1 is related to the second element of the first array [A, [B, C, D]] where element 0 = A element 1 is [B, C, D] and there's no element 2  it should be like calling the array element arr[0][2] but this syntax doesn't work in this context with key=itemgetter(1))

Comment: @Will  Thanks man that's what I need!!

Comment: @NickPV feel free to mark the answer you need as "accepted"

Answer (score 1):

Just define a function that decides on the key to use.
You can use a partial function to create this function based on the key index

```
from functools import partial

def sort_key(si, x):
    return x[1][si]

sort_index = 1  # or 1 or 2

partial_sort_key = partial(sort_key, sort_index)

print(sorted(arr, key=partial_sort_key))
```